# How to enumerate supported permission names in navigator.permissions?

Tags: javascript, permissions, navigator

In a given browser environment, the supported [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions) will likely differ from [the registry spec](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#enumdef-permissionname).

At the time of my writing this question, the spec list includes the following names:

- `accelerometer`
- `ambient-light-sensor`
- `background-fetch`
- `background-sync`
- `bluetooth`
- `camera`
- `clipboard-read`
- `clipboard-write`
- `device-info`
- `display-capture`
- `geolocation`
- `gyroscope`
- `magnetometer`
- `microphone`
- `midi`
- `nfc`
- `notifications`
- `persistent-storage`
- `push`
- `speaker`

The environment support might be not only a subset of the spec list, but also additional permissions not listed in the spec. For example, Chrome 83 supports `periodic-background-sync`. (I've included a code snippet to demonstrate.)

How can I get an enumerated list of the names of the supported permissions in the current environment? How can I **programmatically** know what's possible?

```js
// ✅ = supported
// ❌ = not supported

const getPermissionStatus = name => navigator.permissions.query({name});

const logSupportedPermissions = async (...names) => {
  for (const name of names) {
    try {
      const status = await getPermissionStatus(name);
      console.log(`✅ ${name} (${status.state})`)
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(`❌ ${name}`)
    }
  }
};

const names = [
  'clipboard-write', // listed, works in Chrome 83
  'periodic-background-sync', // not listed, but works in Chrome 83
  'display-capture', // listed, but throws in Chrome 83
  'a-nonexistent-permission-name', // not listed, throws
];

logSupportedPermissions(...names);
```

Comment: I think the first line has an issue: you have created a function that wraps navigator.permissions.query but that function, according to mdn, requires an object containing key value pairs, but you are just passing a string, so what is being called is navigator.permissions.query({'clipboard-write'}). You need to actually call navigator.permissions.query({name: 'clipboard-write'). Change the first line to: ```const getPermissionStatus = name => navigator.permissions.query({'name': name});``` and see if that works.

Comment: @leisheng See https://stackoverflow.com/a/38948332/438273

Comment: read the sources: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/permissions/permission_descriptor.idl?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2Fchromium%2Fsrc%2Fthird_party%2Fblink%2Frenderer%2Fmodules%2Fpermissions%2Fpermission_descriptor.idl

Comment: @AlexNikulin I see that I can look at specific tags which correspond to release versions. Is there a similar (versioned, simple-to-parse) file for Firefox, Edge, etc.? I can get the browser version and then fetch and parse these.

Comment: @jsejcksn as you can see mozilla refers to chromium too. Edge is webkit too, so you can took from chromium sources (and commented properties as well)

Comment: firefox sources https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/remote/test/puppeteer/src/protocol.d.ts#874

Answer (score 3):

Take it from browser sources

- [chromium](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/blink/renderer/modules/permissions/permission_descriptor.idl?originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2Fchromium%2Fsrc%2Fthird_party%2Fblink%2Frenderer%2Fmodules%2Fpermissions%2Fpermission_descriptor.idl)
- [firefox](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/remote/test/puppeteer/src/protocol.d.ts#874)
- [firefox second](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/dom/webidl/Permissions.webidl#10)
- [Opera](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera/blob/bed27accab90077fbf98eabf5b503219834f1b8f/src/_extensions/declare-permissions.md)

Comment: Source for Safari? Opera?

Comment: Safari and Opera are forks of chromium

Comment: Safari is not a fork of Chromium. Chrome started as a fork of WebKit. Will you please provide a source for Opera?

Answer (score 0):

The Permissions API is still under development and the [current spec](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#permissions-interface) doesn't allow for checking which permissions are granted nor which ones are available unless queried by the async method you've integrated above.

Perhaps one day something like `Object.keys(Permissions.prototype)` will become available, just like `Object.keys(Navigator.prototype)`

For now you'll need to keep consulting the "Browser Support" section in MDN or the [registry](https://w3c.github.io/permissions/#permission-registry).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. However, this is a non-answer to the question that I asked.

Answer (score 0):

Like joe said, this is currently not possible, at least not in Chrome 83. The list of supported permissions are not directly accessible from JavaScript, as they only exist in C++ the browser is compiled from.

Note how `navigator.permissions.query.toString()` in Chrome returns `ƒ query() { [native code] }`.

That said, [Chromium and the Blink engine are open source](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/), so we can take a peek at what's going on.

[This file](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/modules/permissions/permission_utils.cc) has a big function called `ParsePermissionDescriptor` that handles the logic of converting the string passed to `query` and checking it against available permissions. We can examine what this function does:

```cpp
  PermissionDescriptor* permission =
      NativeValueTraits<PermissionDescriptor>::NativeValue(
          script_state->GetIsolate(), raw_descriptor.V8Value(),
          exception_state);
  if (exception_state.HadException())
    return nullptr;
  const String& name = permission->name();
  if (name == "geolocation")
    return CreatePermissionDescriptor(PermissionName::GEOLOCATION);
```

So we get the name, then compare it against a string. If they're equal, we return a new `PermissionDescriptor`.

```cpp
  if (name == "clipboard-read" || name == "clipboard-write") {
    PermissionName permission_name = PermissionName::CLIPBOARD_READ;
    if (name == "clipboard-write")
      permission_name = PermissionName::CLIPBOARD_WRITE;
    ClipboardPermissionDescriptor* clipboard_permission =
        NativeValueTraits<ClipboardPermissionDescriptor>::NativeValue(
            script_state->GetIsolate(), raw_descriptor.V8Value(),
            exception_state);
    return CreateClipboardPermissionDescriptor(
        permission_name, clipboard_permission->allowWithoutGesture(),
        clipboard_permission->allowWithoutSanitization());
  }
```

But we're also dealing with these more complex permissions with their own constructors, like `CreateClipboardPermissionDescriptor`.

At any rate, you can look through the file and try all the values checked by `name == "some-string"` (notice how the error messages returned for disabled permissions are what you get back with your `logSupportedPermissions` function) , but I don't know how you'd be able to get that programmatically.